# Is is possible to make a cycling variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables

I want to make a variable that can cycle around a specific value

Like if I set i to cycle from 0 to 7 and put i=5, then I add 2 to i it will be 7, I add 3 to i it will be 0, I add 4 to i it will be 1, and so on.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is unclear. Please explain properly what you want, what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: now that you have an accepted answer i would suggest you do a task of generate random number between 0 to 100 (that will help you better understand how % works . hint random % 100 ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with primitives in an automated way, but you can use `%`:

```
(5 + 2) % 8 == 7
(5 + 3) % 8 == 0
```

If you were building a class, you could add `addTo()` or `increment()` methods that observe the bounds, but you'd lose some performance due to boxing.

Comment: Really did not think of that. Thanks

Comment: A faster way to do `% 8` for positive numbers is `& 7` as it is a simpler operation.